# finding the closest rivals in the group

Tags: r, min

i have a unbalaned panel company data as followed：

```
time           comid    group       sales           closeone
1988m1        tw1701        1        2.45             tw1410
1988m1        tw1213        1        1.98             tw1701
1988m1        tw1707        1        2.67        
1988m1        tw2702        1        9.45        
1988m1        tw9902        1        4.16        
1988m1        tw1410        1        2.57        
1988m2        tw2601        3        27.44            tw2505
1988m2        tw2505        3        9.49        
1988m2        tw1413        3        1.46        
1988m2        tw2901        3        3.74        
1988m2        tw1417        4        1.87             tw1506    
1988m2        tw1506        4        3.24        
1988m2        tw1215        4        3.58
```

my aim is to find out the closest rival within the same group and time.

just as column colseone show.  for example,

in the closeone first row ,tw1410 is  under group=1,time=1988m1 condition,

abs(all sales - sales of tw1701) and find the min value and exclude zero(i.e. can't be itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you were downvoted, I didn't think this was trivial. This is how I solved it. There might be an easier way. I couldn't get data.table operations to set the final value so had to use a for loop.

basically it sorts the data by groups, calculated the difference between the rows above and below within the same group, finds the min of those two values, and then sets the value of the rival by that reference.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
setorder(dat,time,group,-sales)

dat[ , "Diff" := c(NA, diff(sales)), by = .(time,group)]
dat[ , "Diff2" := c(diff((sales)),NA), by = .(time,group)]


dat[ ,"Min" := ifelse(abs(Diff) < abs(Diff2), 1, 2)]
dat[ ,"Min" := ifelse(is.na(Diff),2,Min)]
dat[ ,"Min" := ifelse(is.na(Diff2),1,Min)]

dat[, "Rival" := NA]

for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  if(dat$Min[i] == 2){
    dat$Rival[i] = as.character(dat[i+1,comid])
  }else{
    dat$Rival[i] = as.character(dat[i-1,comid])
  }
}

> dat
      time  comid group sales   Diff  Diff2 Min  Rival
 1: 1988m1 tw2702     1  9.45     NA  -5.29   2 tw9902
 2: 1988m1 tw9902     1  4.16  -5.29  -1.49   2 tw1707
 3: 1988m1 tw1707     1  2.67  -1.49  -0.10   2 tw1410
 4: 1988m1 tw1410     1  2.57  -0.10  -0.12   1 tw1707
 5: 1988m1 tw1701     1  2.45  -0.12  -0.47   1 tw1410
 6: 1988m1 tw1213     1  1.98  -0.47     NA   1 tw1701
 7: 1988m2 tw2601     3 27.44     NA -17.95   2 tw2505
 8: 1988m2 tw2505     3  9.49 -17.95  -5.75   2 tw2901
 9: 1988m2 tw2901     3  3.74  -5.75  -2.28   2 tw1413
10: 1988m2 tw1413     3  1.46  -2.28     NA   1 tw2901
11: 1988m2 tw1215     4  3.58     NA  -0.34   2 tw1506
12: 1988m2 tw1506     4  3.24  -0.34  -1.37   1 tw1215
13: 1988m2 tw1417     4  1.87  -1.37     NA   1 tw1506
```

If anyone has a better solution I'd love to see it.

**EDIT**

The reason I couldn't get this into vector format apparently was because comid was a factor. I have no idea why that would break the function, but when I changed it to character it worked.

Replace the for loop with this:

```
dat$comid = as.character(dat$comid)
dat[, "Rival" := ifelse(Min == 2, shift(comid, type = "lead"), shift(comid, type = "lag"))]

> dat
      time  comid group sales   Diff  Diff2 Min  Rival
 1: 1988m1 tw2702     1  9.45     NA  -5.29   2 tw9902
 2: 1988m1 tw9902     1  4.16  -5.29  -1.49   2 tw1707
 3: 1988m1 tw1707     1  2.67  -1.49  -0.10   2 tw1410
 4: 1988m1 tw1410     1  2.57  -0.10  -0.12   1 tw1707
 5: 1988m1 tw1701     1  2.45  -0.12  -0.47   1 tw1410
 6: 1988m1 tw1213     1  1.98  -0.47     NA   1 tw1701
 7: 1988m2 tw2601     3 27.44     NA -17.95   2 tw2505
 8: 1988m2 tw2505     3  9.49 -17.95  -5.75   2 tw2901
 9: 1988m2 tw2901     3  3.74  -5.75  -2.28   2 tw1413
10: 1988m2 tw1413     3  1.46  -2.28     NA   1 tw2901
11: 1988m2 tw1215     4  3.58     NA  -0.34   2 tw1506
12: 1988m2 tw1506     4  3.24  -0.34  -1.37   1 tw1215
13: 1988m2 tw1417     4  1.87  -1.37     NA   1 tw1506
```

That should run a lot faster.

Comment: i got "replace has length zero" message, so i changed to start with 2:
for(i in 2:nrow(dat)) . then it works.

by the way , the data has 30 thousand obs, it runs very long. what if i extract some obs as experiment group and match pop.

samp<-dat[(3,7,8,9),]
dplyr::left_join(samp,pop,by=c("comid","time) )

would it be less time-consuming way to find the close rival in the experiment group ref to pop.

Comment: @changjx all of the data.table operations should be done almost instantly. Is it the for loop that's slow? I can try to fix that part. And if replace has length 0 double check the +/- i in the for loop. Might be backwards.

Comment: @changjx so thinking about this a little more I think we can replace the for loop using shift in data.table. I can play around with that tomorrow.

Comment: done, it takes nearly 3.5 hr to run through the "300 thousand obs" XD

Comment: there is a stata command -cond-, cond(min==1,twid[_n-1],twid[_n+1]). in seconds, it was done.

Comment: @changjx Try the new code. That should be a lot faster.

Comment: @changjx I'm curious on the performance of the new code. Was that able to match the time of stata?

Comment: @ Kristofersen,i don't know the difference, bz both are speedy, less than a second. and certainly super improvement w.r.t loop. great thx  to  u^^"

Comment: bz of some event to twid, some twid are recorded at certain time in eventdata. 
like this
eventdata<-c("1988m1","tw1707" ,"1988m1" ,"tw1410" ,"1988m2" ,"tw1215")
How to delete obs from dat according to eventdata?
in sql i can do something like that:

DELETE FROM eventdata
WHERE eventdata.comid=dt.comid and eventdata.time=dt.time